# C# generic method with one parameter of multiple types

Tags: c#, generics

I'm having a problem writing a generic method to retrieve AD Groups or Users with a parameter that can be one of two types - either `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement GroupPrincipal` or `UserPrincipal`

The method is as follows:-

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetGroupsOrUsers<T>(T GroupOrUserPrincipal)
{
   PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();
   ps.QueryFilter = GroupOrUserPrincipal;

   etc.........
}
```

The problem is the GroupOrUserPrincipal is showing the following error:-

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal

Am I able to do this or am I missing something ?

Comment: Quick question. Why don't you write one method for groups and another one for users?

Comment: That's what I had done but just wanted to streamline it a bit using just one method - there is more code in this method so really it was to avoid duplication.

Comment: GroupPrincipal and UserPrincipal are derived from Principal?

Comment: Couple of good answers pointing to a type constraint - but those will fail if you don't want your code to work for any other principal types, e.g. a ComputerPrincipal (i.e. did you mean that you want it to work for the two types you've listed, and no others?)

Comment: @J. Kommer - my point was, the OP requested something that would work for `GroupPrincipal` and `UserPrincipal` - I was trying to ask whether that was an *exclusive* list of types that this method should work for...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah, apologies - I misread your original comment as can, not can't. (Suffer from dyslexia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should restrict `T` to types that your method makes sense for:

```
private static IENumerable<string> GetGroupsOrUsers<T>(T GroupOrUserPrincipal)
        where T : Principal
{
      // .....
```

That prevents calls of `GetGroupsOrUsers<int>`, and lets `T` be implicitly converted to `Principal`, fixing your error (or so I hope).

Comment: Very cool. Never thought about doing this. Do you know the Pro's and Con's of using this?

Comment: @thats_how_i_feel: You can read more about this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4. I don't know any cons, pros are mostly type safety and re-usability.

Comment: Well I like it. I feel like it encourages better object oriented programming. If you have three classes that all have a method that does essentially the same thing and you want to make another method in another class that utilizes their similar methods, you shouldn't have to make three new methods, right? Anyways, [this section of Wikipedia's C# page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_syntax#Type-parameters) helped me understand type parameters better.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a [type parameter constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx); for example:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetGroupsOrUsers<T>(T GroupOrUserPrincipal) where T: Principal
```

This limits the classes that can be used as T to only classes of type `Principal` or a subclass of `Principal`. The C# compiler then knows that everything passed to `GetGroupsOrUsers(...)` will be of a type compatible with `Principal`  and will no longer error.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly you want to look at [Generic Contraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#csharp_generics_topic4) in particular a derivation contraint where your various T objects all impliment a given interterface.  Eg

```
where T : Principle
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a cast in this line:

```
ps.QueryFilter = (Principal) GroupOrUserPrincipal;
```