# Method parameter to accept multiple types

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I'm developing an application which in I got multiple types of `RichTextBox`s which I've customized `(RichTextBox,RichAlexBox,TransparentRichTextBox)`.

I want to create a method to accept all those types plus some other parameters.

```
private void ChangeFontStyle(RichTextBox,RichAlexBox,TransparentRichTextBox rch,
                                                         FontStyle style, bool add)
{
  //Doing somthing with rch.Rtf
}
```

I've searched through StackOverFlow and found some answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965580/c-sharp-generics-syntax-for-multiple-type-parameter-constraints) which I couldn't figure out how to use them to solve my problem

```
void foo<TOne, TTwo>()  //There's just one parameter here
   where TOne : BaseOne //and I can't figure out how to define my other two parameters        
   where TTwo : BaseTwo
```

I also tried overloading as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10833996/2263683) offers,

```
private void ChangeFontStyle(TransparentRichTextBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add);
private void ChangeFontStyle(RichAlexBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add);
private void ChangeFontStyle(RichTextBox rch,FontStyle style, bool add)
  {
    //Some codes
  }
```

But I encounter this error

```
'ChangeFontStyle(RichAlexBox, FontStyle, bool)' 
         must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
```

Here's some other Q&A I checked:

[Generic method with multiple constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588643/generic-method-with-multiple-constraints)

[Can I create a generic method that accepts two different types in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954009/can-i-create-a-generic-method-that-accepts-two-different-types-in-c-sharp)

[C# generic method with one parameter of multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062782/c-sharp-generic-method-with-one-parameter-of-multiple-types)

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `TransparentRichTextBox` and `RichAlexBox` are both subtypes of
[`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx), then you only need one method signature:

```
private void ChangeFontStyle(RichTextBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add)
{
    //Doing somthing with rch.Rtf
}
```

Otherwise, you will need to implement the method for every overload:

```
private void ChangeFontStyle(TransparentRichTextBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add)
{
    //Some codes
}

private void ChangeFontStyle(RichAlexBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add)
{
    //Some codes
}

private void ChangeFontStyle(RichTextBox rch,FontStyle style, bool add)
{
    //Some codes
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are properly using inheritance, you don't need generics or overloading:

```
class RichTextBox
{
     // implementation
}

class RichAlexBox : RichTextBox
{
     // implementation
}

class TransparentRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
     // implementation
}

// allows passing in anything that inherits from RichTextBox
private void ChangeFontStyle(RichTextBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add)
{
     // implementation
}
```

As @dotnetkid suggests, another option is to make `ChangeFontStyle` a method in the RichTextBox class and make it virtual so that you can override it when you need to:

```
class RichTextBox
{
     public virtual void ChangeFontStyle(FontStyle style, bool add)
     {
         // implementation
     }

     // implementation
}

class RichAlexBox : RichTextBox
{
     // uses the inherited ChangeFontStyle

     // implementation
}

class TransparentRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
     public override void ChangeFontStyle(FontStyle style, bool add)
     {
         // TransparentRichTextBox-specific implementation
     }

     // implementation
}
```

Comment: I would suggest making ChangeFontStyle into RichTextBox and marking it *Virtual*.

Comment: @dotnetkid That was the best offer ever!

Answer (score 1):

When overloading a method do like this.

```
private void ChangeFontStyle(TransparentRichTextBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add)
{
   // your code
}

private void ChangeFontStyle(RichAlexBox rch, FontStyle style, bool add) 
{
   // your code
}
private void ChangeFontStyle(RichTextBox rch,FontStyle style, bool add)
{
   // your code
}
```

Or you can just use `Control` class as a parameter try like this

```
 private void ChangeFontStyle(Control control,FontStyle style, bool add)
 {
       // your code
 }
```

You can pass any Control you want like `TextBox`, `RichTextBox`, `ComboBox` etc..